# Margins on large devices

Tags: android

Many app's, including the swipe left Google Now screen have a colored background and very large margins to compensate for the small amount of data on tablets, particularly in landscape.

Are there any standard dp dimensions for these margins on particular devices?
I'm aware of the `activity_horizontal_margin` but it's far bigger than that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are [Design Guidelines](https://www.google.com/design/spec/layout/metrics-keylines.html#metrics-keylines-keylines-spacing) available for Android Application.

**Baseline grids** : All components align to an 8dp square baseline grid for mobile, tablet, and desktop. Iconography in toolbars align to a 4dp square baseline grid

**List** : A two-column, left-aligned list with a 56dp floating action button.

**Detail view** : A detail card with a 56dp floating action button.

For e.g.

[image]

Above link contains all information regarding your question.

Better go through it.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm aware of the design guidelines but they don't give examples for this particular style of layout.

Comment: Google provides way to create custom layout..!! Anyone can create anything beautiful. So how Google will be able to give guidelines for that :)